# Swift 3 - identify a particular marker that has been tapped out of many markers on the map (Google Maps SDK iOS)

Tags: ios, swift3, marker, google-maps-sdk-ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to identify a particular marker that has been tapped out of many markers on the map. If a particular marker is tapped, print its coordinates.

How do I go about this?

Below is my attempt, it works for all the markers on the map, not particular one.

First function places all markers on the map

```
func placeMapMarkers() {
    for item in self.finalDictionary as [Dictionary<String, String>] {
        let lat = item["lat"] as! String
        let lon = item["lon"] as! String
        let SpotLat = Double(lat)
        let SpotLon = Double(lon)
        let SpotLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(SpotLat!, SpotLon!)

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.SpotMarker = GMSMarker(position: SpotLocation)
            self.SpotMarker?.title = "Press navigation icon below"
            self.SpotMarker?.map = self.mapView
            self.SpotMarkers.append(self.SpotMarker!)

            //Currently calling didTapMarker function here
            //but it works for all markers on map NOT a particular one
            self.tappedMarker(mapView: self.mapView!, didTapMarker: self.SpotMarker!)
        })
    }
}

//tappedMarker function
func tappedMarker(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker SpotMarker: GMSMarker){
    //Print coordinates here for the particular marker
}
```

Comment: Did you try     "func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {  return false  }" delegate method ?

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much the tappedMarker function I have, isn't it? I am using delegate method.